# Jersey server, servlet 3 and HK2 injection and Vaadin: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries but no Hadoop is used

Tags: hadoop, tomcat, servlets, jersey, hk2

I am using the following Maven dependencies to bring in Jersey and create some services that will run on Tomcat v8.0.36 on windows10:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
```

While starting up Tomcat, I get the following at the console:

```
10:09:25.304 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:382) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:397) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:390) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:274) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:262) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isAuthenticationMethodEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:339) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:333) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.DelegationParam.<init>(DelegationParam.java:36) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverters$StringConstructor$1._fromString(ParamConverters.java:130) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverters$AbstractStringReader.fromString(ParamConverters.java:83) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.convert(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:140) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.access$000(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:57) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor$1.get(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:86) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyUnsafeValueImpl.get(Values.java:426) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.<init>(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:92) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.SingleValueExtractor.<init>(SingleValueExtractor.java:68) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.process(MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.java:111) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.get(MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.java:88) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueParamProvider.get(AbstractValueParamProvider.java:91) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.QueryParamValueParamProvider.createValueProvider(QueryParamValueParamProvider.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueParamProvider.getValueProvider(AbstractValueParamProvider.java:117) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParamValueProvider(ParameterValueHelper.java:172) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:134) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:195) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:104) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:100) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:90) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:899) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:162) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.access$000(ComponentModelValidator.java:91) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator$1.run(ComponentModelValidator.java:152) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:147) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316) ~[jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316) [jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298) [jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256) [jersey-common-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315) [jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282) [jersey-server-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_281]
10:09:25.340 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Getting the .wadl output (http://localhost:8080/docui-ui/api/application.wadl) gives me some extra paths that I have not declared anywhere:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.27 2018-04-10 07:34:57"/>
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:hint="This is simplified WADL with user and core resources only. To get full WADL with extended resources use the query parameter detail. Link: http://localhost:8080/docui-ui/api/application.wadl?detail=true"/>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/docui-ui/api/">
        
        ...other paths that I have declared using annotations...
        
        
        ...paths that I have not declared are the following:...
        
        <resource path="">
            <resource path="{path:.*}">
                <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="path" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
                <method id="get" name="GET">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="offset" style="query" type="xs:string" default="0"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="length" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="renewer" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="buffersize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xattr.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="encoding" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="excludedatanodes" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="fsaction" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="kind" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="service" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="put" name="PUT">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="destination" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="owner" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="group" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="permission" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="overwrite" style="query" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="buffersize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="replication" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="blocksize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="modificationtime" style="query" type="xs:string" default="-1"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="accesstime" style="query" type="xs:string" default="-1"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="renameoptions" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="createparent" style="query" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="token" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="aclspec" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xattr.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xattr.value" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="flag" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="snapshotname" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="oldsnapshotname" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="excludedatanodes" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="delete" name="DELETE">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="recursive" style="query" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="snapshotname" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="post" name="POST">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="sources" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="buffersize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="excludedatanodes" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="newlength" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
            <resource path="/">
                <method id="getRoot" name="GET">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="offset" style="query" type="xs:string" default="0"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="length" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="renewer" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="buffersize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xattr.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="encoding" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="excludedatanodes" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="fsaction" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="kind" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="service" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="postRoot" name="POST">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="sources" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="buffersize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="excludedatanodes" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="newlength" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="deleteRoot" name="DELETE">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="recursive" style="query" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="snapshotname" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="putRoot" name="PUT">
                    <request>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="delegation" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="user.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="doas" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="op" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="destination" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="owner" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="group" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="permission" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="overwrite" style="query" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="buffersize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="replication" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="blocksize" style="query" type="xs:string" default="null"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="modificationtime" style="query" type="xs:string" default="-1"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="accesstime" style="query" type="xs:string" default="-1"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="renameoptions" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="createparent" style="query" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="token" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="aclspec" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xattr.name" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xattr.value" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="flag" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="snapshotname" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="oldsnapshotname" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="excludedatanodes" style="query" type="xs:string" default=""/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
        
        
    </resources>
</application>
```

I am also using Vaadin 7.5 as my framework of choice.

I am not using Hadoop and I don't need to for this project. Should I just "obey" the suggestion in the exception text and download winutils.exe etc. or is there another way to make the exception go away?

Comment: Jersey does not depend on Hadoop, one of your other libraries must depend on it.

Comment: Yes, but this exception in the logs occurred only after bringing in these 3 dependencies that have nothing to do with Hadoop. I suspect the HK2 injection dependency (if I change it to Cdi I don't get this exception). But why does HK2 need Hadoop?

Comment: Hk2 doesn't need it either. You have something else on your Java executable that's trying to load Hadoop native libraries. The fact you have `at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.DelegationParam` means that's part of the classpath

Comment: So there must be a dependency that is brought in from the three shown above. I cannot explain it otherwise.

Comment: You must have a REST method, with unusual parameters types that causes the instantiation of `DelegationParam`, while trying to resolve the types. Can you set a breakpoint on the constructors of `DelegationParam` and check the argument of `ResourceMethodValidator#visitResourceMethod`?

Comment: This makes sense. So, I added the output of .wadl to show some extra paths that are published and also added the extra info that I use Vaadin. If it's not helping then I will go ahead and add the breakpoints.

Comment: Looks like the [WebHDFS REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) registered itself to your application.

Comment: How can you tell? Is there a specific parameter that gives it away in the wadl file?

Comment: [This javadoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/web/resources/NamenodeWebHdfsMethods.html) corresponds to the methods exposed by your server.

Comment: I see. So I've got a WebHDFS api registering itself from (what I believe) HK2 dependency. Any ideas here?

Comment: I removed all Jersey from pom.xml and looked at the libs from other libs. Hadoop was still coming in!

The HK2 dependency showed a "need" for Hadoop but because of another dependency and not HK2 itself. I deleted all dependencies and brought them back one by one.

Apache SolR brought Hadoop as a dependency even if I'm not using HDFS but the local filesystem. Specifically <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId> <artifactId>solr-cell</artifactId>

Thank you all for your comments and help.